# Inserting logo from PDF to word processor

Tags: vector, logo, client-relations, file-format

I want to provide a logo design to a client in a vector format for print. I want them to be able to access it to apply to text documents in various word processors as they choose, and hoped for it to be scalable. I have seen advice that PDF is the best way to provide scalable vector graphics for print. I am also providing PNGs for web use at fixed scales.

I was testing the process of PDF for print use. I made a PDF with the logo, and tried to copy it into Pages - no result! I pasted it into Open Office and got a jagged edge on parts of the logo (see below.) Some of the vectors are not jagged, but the ones around the skull are.

1. Does anyone know the reason that some edges are jagged and how to prevent this?
2. Can anyone advise on how to make the logo very accessible (e.g. so it can be copied into pages if required)?
3. What do others do to provide files to clients for print?

Thanks all

[image]

Comment: Actually PNG is often best for word processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft word, Power Point, etc. the best thing is to **export a PNG** and then import it as an image. 
If it's for a printed document make sure you export the right resolution!

Comment: Thank you. I have provided PNGs for web use. Looks like I need to provide PNGs for print use too, and leave the PDF as a source file if a designer requires it? What size PNGs would you normally provide a client?